# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate removes not updated properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    facebook: {
        name: String,
        email: String,
        customerId: String
    }
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

When I update a part of this document using `findByIdAndUpdate`

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { 
    $set: { 
        facebook: {
            name: name 
         }
    }
});
```

`name` gets updated, while `email` and `customerId` get removed (unset?).

I didn't find this documented.

Is there a way to update only specific document properties with `findByIdAndUpdate`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

FindByIdAndUpdate is actually Issues a mongodb findAndModify update command by a documents id.

The point is you are setting an object to overwrite the old object. if you want to update a field you need to modify your update object.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { 
$set: { 
    'facebook.name':name       
 }
});
```

This will only update the name field keeping rest of the field of the old object.

Comment: yes, thanks.  i just found it myself in mongodb docs.  do i have to use $set at all?

Comment: Of course yes if you dont use the $set it will update the doc to only update object removing all old fields.

Comment: well, it doesn't.  i just tested it without set like this: User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { 'facebook.name':name }) and it kept all old fields.

Comment: It may be working with mongoose other wise in mongoshell it produces the error without set